# DataGridView CellDrag too sensitive

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I have a datagridview control on winforms with the following event to drag 'row' out of datagrid:

```
    private void gridOperations_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
        {

            if (Math.Abs(e.X - mouseDownPos.X) >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Width || Math.Abs(e.Y - mouseDownPos.Y) >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Height)
            {
                string[] filesToDrag = { "tmp/generated.log" };
                gridOperations.DoDragDrop(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, filesToDrag), DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is I also have click and double click events on datagridview, the double click event almost never gets executed at first, unless I don't move my mouse at all when clicking. how can I add a 'thershold' so that if I hold mouse down and drag cell for 3 pixels, then it will trigger gridOperations.DoDragDrop? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use an integer counter.
Every time the Event is fired you increment the int and if it is reaches your treshold you execute the rest of the Code and reset it to 0.

like:

```
private int thCount = 0;
    private void gridOperations_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left && thCount==5)
        {
            //... 
            thCount = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            thCount++;
        }
    }
```

hope i could help you